# Splitting a string into a two separate lists of numbers and letters -python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

The title sort of says it all.  For example:
I want to split

```
stringtosplit = 'hello57world'
```

into

```
letters = ['h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d']
numbers = ['5', '7']
```

then make both of them back into strings,

```
letters = 'helloworld'
numbers = '57'
```

is there any **neat** way to do this?  I want to keep my code as concise as possible.  Numbers and letters can occur anywhere in the string and whitespace and special characters are already filtered out.

Comment: have you attempted doing this at all? are you lost? or just asking people to do it for you?

Comment: Take a look at `str.isalpha` and `str.isdigit`.

Comment: I actually came up with aj8uppal's implementation before I did it but was just checking if it was actually the shortest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> stringtosplit = 'hello57world' 
>>> letters = []
>>> numbers = []
>>> for k in stringtosplit:
...     if k.isalpha() == True:
...         letters.append(k)
...     elif k.isdigit() == True:
...         numbers.append(k)
... 
>>> letters
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> numbers
['5', '7']
>>> letters = ''.join(letters)
>>> numbers = ''.join(numbers)
>>> letters
'helloworld'
>>> numbers
'57'
```

Use [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to check if the variable is a letter, and [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if it is a number. Then use `''.join(str)` to convert from a `list` to a `str`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: And I believe you do have enough reputation :)

Comment: @aj8uppal: How did you create your output? Is it an automated Python thing? Or did you just type it out, with the `>>>` and `...` and the outputs...? I don't know Python...if that isn't obvious ;)

Comment: I opened a python shell and typed each line in, one by one. I then copied it over and pasted it here. Open a python shell by going into your command prompt (Terminal on OSX) and typing in `python`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you could do it like:

```
>>> stringtosplit = 'hello57world'
>>> onlyLetter = "".join([i for i in stringtosplit if i.isalpha()])
>>> onlyLetter
'helloworld'
>>> onlyDig = "".join([i for i in stringtosplit if i.isdigit()])
>>> onlyDig
```

The function i.isalpha() will test whether i is a letter, and i.isdigit() test whether i is a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and generator comprehensions:

```
>>> s = 'hello57world'
>>> alphas = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
>>> nums = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())
>>> print alphas, nums
helloworld 57
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

letters = []
numbers = []

for achar in thestring:
    if achar in string.ascii_letters:
        letters.append(achar)
    if achar in string.digits:
        letters.append(achar)

letters_string = "".join(letters)
numbers_string = "".join(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
import re

stringtosplit = 'hello57world'
letters = ''.join(re.findall('([a-zA-Z])', stringtosplit))
numbers = ''.join(re.findall('([0-9])', stringtosplit))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tools:**

1. You should use this Python Regex with group. I belive that will provide most cleanup way:

   ```
   r = r"(?P<first>[a-z]*)(?P<num>[0-9]*)(?P<last>[a-z]*)"
   #           ^^^^^         ^^^^              ^^^
   #    before numbers      numbers        after numbers  
   # any group can be absent
   ```
2. Then you can use [`re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

   > Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples. if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

**Test-Cases:**

```
>>> re.findall(r, 'hello57world')[0]  # your string 
('hello', '57', 'world')
>>> re.findall(r, 'hello57')[0]  # word after number ""
('hello', '57', '')
>>> re.findall(r, '3234abcd')[0] # word before number ""
('', '3234', 'abcd')
>>> re.findall(r, '450')[0]  # only number
('', '450', '')
>>> re.findall(r, 'hello')[0]  # number is ""
('hello', '', '')
>>> re.findall(r, '')[0] # empty string
('', '', '')
```

**Code:**
Now you can write simple code in three lines:

```
>>> stringtosplit = 'hello57world' 
>>> r = r"(?P<first>[a-z]*)(?P<num>[0-9]*)(?P<last>[a-z]*)"
>>> f, n, l = re.findall(r, stringtosplit)[0]
>>> n
'57'
>>> f + l
'helloworld'
```

Give it a try!!

Comment: Forgot to add, I can use `re.I` to ignore case as `re.findall(r, stringtosplit, re.I)[0]`